# Problems uploading codeigniter project from localhost to live server

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed a project in codeigniter. Now i want to move it from localhost to a live server. But i moved it, the website opens the first time and when i refresh the page, then it just shows the blank page. I tried in another browser, there was also the same problem. After 30 minutes when i tried to open the website, it opens the first time and then again on refreshing the site, the blank page appears.

Upon closing the browser and opening it again, the page opens first time and then after refreshing it does not work neither it goes to other pages.

I do not understand where is the problem. Please someone should help me.

Comment: No i am using codeigniter 2.2.

Comment: I have included it. Actually when I open the browser first time and I run my project, it runs fine. But when the first page of my project opens, after that when i click on a link it does not open and shows a blank page. Refreshing the same page, also makes that page blank. Error reporting is also on, that also doesn't show any error.

Comment: Provide the contents of your `config.php` also maybe provide us with your file structure. You can genereate one here: http://FileStructureGenerator.com

Comment: I have posted my config.php file in the following answer, as it is too long i can't post it in comment @CodeGodie

Comment: No one is answering my question. Please someone should answer my question. Your answers will be really appreciated.

Comment: I can help you remotely through Teamviewer. I will be on 4 hours from now. Let me know if you want to do that. There are just too many things that could be happening

Comment: Yes you must help me. I am on upto 4 hour from now.

Comment: ok go on Teamviewer and give me your credentials. I will remotely log in so you can show me and see if I can help

Comment: Ok These are my credentials. ID: 360 516 010 Password: 2728 @CodeGodie

Comment: @CodeGodie connect once again, connection was lost ID:360 516 010 password: 3111

Comment: please connect once again, connection was lost @CodeGodie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Folowing are the contents of my config.php file.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysyite/folder/subfolder/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['cache_path'] = '';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Above are the contents of my config.php. @CodeGodie

Comment: can you also provide the contents of `index.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the index.php file.

```
 switch (dirname(__FILE__)){

        case 'C:\wamp\www\ems\public_html' :
            $env = 'development';
            break;

        default :
            $env = 'production';
            break;
    }

define('ENVIRONMENT', $env);


if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
 {
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

$system_path = '../system';

$application_folder = '../application';
```

Please someone should help, I am in a very trouble and I have very less time for this project. @CodeGodie

Comment: so why is it that your index is pointing to your system path one directory back? did you move files around? It would really help if you give us a visual of your file structure.

Comment: That is because my system and application folders are one level back. That is OK. It seems to me that the problem is in the .htacces file @CodeGodie